# SwiftUI Image showing gap at top?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui, statusbar

I have the following code I am testing out for the sake of learning about MatchedGeometry and more.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var match = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    @State var snapshot:UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            if !match {
                AView { img in
                    snapshot = img
                    withAnimation {
                        match.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: namespace, properties: .frame)
            }
            
            
            if match && snapshot != nil {
                Color.clear.ignoresSafeArea().overlay(
                    BView(image: snapshot!)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: namespace, properties: .frame)
                        .frame(width: 600, height: 600)
                        .transition(.scale)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                match.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
        }
        // .statusBar(hidden: true) // <-- THIS REMOVES THE RED GAP IN BView, but I want to keep the status bar. I want BView to work regadless.
    }
    
}


struct AView: View {
    
    var didTap:(_ img:UIImage)->()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image("island")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
//            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .border(.purple)
            .onTapGesture {
                didTap(snapshot(size: geo.size))
            }
            
        }
        .border(.yellow)
    }
    
}



struct BView: View {
    
    @State var image:UIImage
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
    }
}



extension View {
    
    func snapshot(origin: CGPoint = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = size == .zero ? controller.view.intrinsicContentSize : size
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: origin, size: targetSize)

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
    
}
```

It shows this:

[image]

There are two things I am not sure why they work the way they do:

1. Why am I getting a gap in the `BView` (shown in red)? I was expecting the image to fill `BView` and not have that top gap. I tried ignoring save area etc... but no luck.
2. Why is the image in the `AView` not centered horizontally?

How can I fix both, meaning, I want the image to be centered and fill `BView` (aspect fill), and I want the image in `AView` to be horizontally centered.

Image comes from assets, file I found at:
https://cruisewhitsundays.imgix.net/2019/05/DayDream_Dec2018_03_0395.jpg

Comment: 1: It is GeometryReader - uncomment that .frame and add clipped after it. 2: it is snapshot - logic generates wrong image.

Comment: When you say you *"want the image in `AView` to be horizontally centered"* ... do you mean you want the **full image** shown in the aspect ratio of the **image**? Or, do you want to keep your 1:1 ratio (300x300 frame) showing only the center of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-using `ZStack` in your `AView` and `BView` ...

Take a look at this, and see if you get the desired results:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var match = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    @State var snapshot:UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            if !match {
                AView { img in
                    snapshot = img
                    withAnimation {
                        match.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .clipped()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: namespace, properties: .frame)
            }
            
            if match && snapshot != nil {
                Color.clear.ignoresSafeArea().overlay(
                    BView(image: snapshot!)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: namespace, properties: .frame)
                        .frame(width: 600, height: 600)
                        .clipped()
                        .transition(.scale)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                match.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
        }

    }
    
}

struct AView: View {
    
    var didTap:(_ img:UIImage)->()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Image("island")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .border(.purple)
                .onTapGesture {
                    didTap(snapshot(size: geo.size))
                }
        }
        .border(.yellow)
    }
    
}

struct BView: View {
    
    @State var image:UIImage
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    }
    
}

extension View {
    
    func snapshot(origin: CGPoint = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = size == .zero ? controller.view.intrinsicContentSize : size
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: origin, size: targetSize)
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
    
}
```